# Create a volumetric cone shape in eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

Anyone know how to create a volumetric cone in EEVEE? I know that volume scatter is able to follow a shape in CYCLE but not in EEVEE... I found how to create a sphere thanks to the nodes, but unable to make a cone.
Thanks for your feedback
Sorry... My English is so bad

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to  [Inigo Quilez](http://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm), here's a signed-distance function from the surface of a cone of a given pitch angle.

```
float sdCone( vec3 p, vec2 c )
{
  // c is the sin/cos of the angle
  float q = length(p.xy);
  return dot(c,vec2(q,p.z));
}
```

I would have done it another way, but this is *much* simpler... it boils down to the [distance from a point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).(The vector projection proof)

[image]

Here, the cone is in the space of an Empty, so you can move it around. You set the angle at the 'Angle' input in radians, and can adjust the scale of the cone with the 'Threshold' setting, and the density inside it by multiplying the result.

[image]

I tested it on a stack of planes.. it is filling the volume, with the 'Less Than' (the threshold).. if you use a 'Compare' instead, you can capture just a shell.

[image]