# Eevee volume emission texture space is cubic even for a cylinder solid

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, emission

I created a solid cylinder

[image: top view solid]

with an emitting volume material. In render mode, the glow looks cubic instead of following the circular profile of the cylinder. This could be because the texture space is cubic.

[image: top view render]

How do I make the emission look cylindrical? Or, in general, is there any other way to make a cylindrical glowing volume?

Comment: Switch to cycles

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169651